# Ubuntu in Virtualbox crawling

Tags: virtualbox, macbook-air, ubuntu-12.10

My brother has a Macbook Air and recently decided to try Ubuntu, so we set up Virtualbox and installed 12.10, it works fine but there definitely is a lag in visual effects, I know a MacBook Air is a lightweight in many aspects and I shouldn't expect much but I was wondering if there's any room for improving performance in the guest Ubuntu.

As a side note I installed the Guest Additions but it didn't seem to do much, we get to Full Screen now though.

Comment: Did you add too many cores (more than what your physical computer has)?

Comment: Nope, left it at default value. We did increase the RAM up to 2.5 GBs (out of 4)